# Minimum sum of digits for a polynomial

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, functions, summation, modular-arithmetic

> Given $n$ a natural number (greater than $0$) and $p(n)$ a polynomial, $p(n) = 2n^2 + 43n + 502$. Defining the arithmetic function $s(k) : \mathbb{N}^*  \to \mathbb{N}^*$, the sum of the digits of the number $k$. Find $\min s(p(n))$. (Problem proposed for JMBO practice)

*Approach 1.* $s(a + b) \leq s(a) + s(b)$, therefore $s(p(n)) \leq s(n(2n + 43)) + 7$. But $s(ab) \leq s(a)s(b)$, therefore $s(n(2n + 43)) \leq s(n)s(2n + 43)$. Applying the sum property, then $s(2n + 43) \leq s(2n) + 7$. By product property, $s(2n) \leq 2s(n)$.

To sum up, $s(p(n)) \leq s(n)[2s(n) + 7] + 7 = 2s(n)^2 + 7s(n) + 7$, from which I'm stuck.

*Approach 2.* Let's prove $\min s(p(n)) = 7$. Let's prove it's impossible to have $s(p(n)) \in \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$. As $p(n) \not\equiv 0 \mod 3$, $s(n) \not\in \{3, 6\}$. Also, if $s(p(n)) = 1$, $p(n) = 10^q$, $q \in \mathbb{N}$. But $p(n) \not\equiv 0 \mod 10$, so it's impossible. For the last numbers, I haven't found any approach.

Thanks!

Comment: $p(59)=10001$ which is obviously minimal, though I don't have a clever way to get to that case.

Comment: @lulu You should prove that no $p(n)$ is a power of $10$. Do you mind checking my answer?

Comment: @lulu Thanks a lot for your calculation. I can prove that $s(p(x)) \neq 1$, so the problem is done.

Comment: @lulu How did you get $n=59$?

Comment: @LightYagami  Brute force search. I think, but have not shown, that no other $n$ works.  Might be possible to prove that without too much strain, haven't tried.